# Where do I put my Python packages on Mac?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

On my Manjaro Linux machine I put my custom packages to `~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/` and Python finds them automatically making them available globally. I've tried doing exactly the same on a MacBook (running Mac OS X 10.9 "Mavericks" with both Python 3.6 and 2.7 installed) and it doesn't seem to work. What is the correct path or where am I to add this path to make it work?

Comment: Try to `import sys; print sys.path`.

Comment: @Maroun `['', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python36.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages']` How do I add a directory under the user home to this list correctly? Or am I actually meant to manually put my code into some one of these already in the list?

Comment: Then I guess it's `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages`.

Comment: @Maroun It seems to be a directory where PIP puts installed packages. I don't think it's a perfect idea to put something there manually. Sure it won't be a serious problem yet I believe there is to be a dedicated directory for DIY libraries not managed by any package managers.

Answer (score 1):

tried this link yet? I think your answer might be in there

https://docs.python.org/3/using/mac.html

Comment: The link doesn't include the actual answer anyway though it gives a clue that setting the `$PYTHONPATH` environment variable may help. Following this idea I've googled upon https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469160-How-do-I-set-PYTHONPATH-and-other-environment-variables-for-Canopy- and added `setenv PYTHONPATH /Users/myname/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages` to `/etc/launchd.conf` as it suggests. This has solved the problem but this can hardly be considered a tidy solution as it affects both Python 3.6 and Python 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

This [GitHub Article](https://gist.github.com/patriciogonzalezvivo/77da993b14a48753efda) lists some steps that could be helpful.

When you install Python it says to **Add PATH to** `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.zshrc`

This is accomplished by:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/share/python:$PATH
```

I hope this solves the problem!